# SQL SUM with Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| PartId | ItemId | Price | Staus |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|  94669 |   3678 |    88 |     1 |
|  94669 |   3679 |    22 |     1 |
|  94669 |   3680 |    30 |     1 |
|  94669 |   3681 |    50 |     4 |
|  94670 |   3678 |    88 |     1 |
|  94670 |   3679 |    22 |     1 |
|  94670 |   3680 |    30 |     1 |
|  94670 |   3681 |    50 |     1 |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```

The expected output is (without status 4)

```
+--------+------------+
| PartId | TotalPrice |
+--------+------------+
|  94669 |        140 |
|  94670 |        190 |
+--------+------------+
```

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: The second column makes no sense.  As for your question, it seems pretty simple . . . `GROUP BY`, `WHERE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  No, I want to select it based on the status,.. I have to omit the records which have status other than 1 and then get the sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty basic aggregation query with a `where` and `group by`.

```
select partid, sum(price) as totalprice
from t
where [status] <> 4
group by partid
```

If you have to omit `status` other than 1, it would be correct to use `status = 1` instead:

```
select partid, sum(price) as totalprice
from t
where [status] = 1
group by partid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT "Part ID", SUM(Price)
FROM (
    SELECT "Part ID", Price
    FROM Table
    WHERE Status <> 4)
GROUP BY "Part ID";
```

Comment: Why the subquery here? It will work but this should just be a single select statement with no subquery. It is super basic aggregation.

Comment: I had just finished writing a complex query with sub-queries pulling that kind of sum. When the hammer is on top of your tool box, you treat problems like nails. I realized that when I read my response a few hours later.